Большая нагрузка на сервер
У меня на сервере стоит hestia. Использую mysql+php. Проект работает по следующему принципу:
человек заходит на index.html, там я ловлю нужные от него данные и отправляю на свой php файл с помощью js. Там в базе я делаю несколько выборок (каждая выборка - это лишь одна строка, целую кучу я не беру). Таблицы, из которых беру строку для проверки  -в основном маленькие, но одна из них на 1.5 миллиона записей(но из неё я тоже беру только 1 уникальную по условию строку, с limit 1). Если все условия пройдены - добавляю в эту большую таблицу новую строку с этим человеком, возвращаю ответ себе же в js и делаю редирект на нужную html страничку в зависимости от ответа.
При точечной нагрузке в моменте примерно в 2-3 человека в секунду сервер начинает показывать огромные цифры нагрузки (600% cpu), люди, вроде, добавляются, если судить по логам, но ответ от сервера не доходит (мой скрипт через какое-то время возвращает 504 ошибку), в итоге редирект не происходит.
Вот конфигурация сервера:

Я понимаю, что информации не так много, но хотелось бы послушать людей на опыте, которые, возможно, сталкивались с подобным и находили какие-то решения. Я знаю много всего, что может повлиять, но не понимаю, как определить точечно проблему, не тыкая пальцем в небо. Заранее благодарю за любую подсказку.

Структуру БД показать можете? Примеры запросов? Индексы?

Для начала стоит локализовать процесс, который потребляет такие ресурсы. Это может быть БД, сервер или вообще какой-то сторонний процесс. Далее можно более детально углубляться в проблему.

Скажите, вы правда думаете, что  limit 1 - это именно то что нужно для ускорения запросов?

Покажите хотя бы значение innodb_buffer_pool_size

@AndrewHobbit что то мне подсказывает, что там вообще нет индексов

@YaMus Согласен. Мне тоже это первое на ум приходит.

@Ипатьев InnoDB Buffer Pool Size in MByte 128.00000000

@AndrewHobbit на тех двух полях, по которым я проверяю, индексов нет, т.к. их просто не может быть, они и не уникальные, и ссылаться мне не на что, т.к. таблиц для связи у меня нет и не нужны в принципе, уникальными они быть по отдельности не могут, их уникальность складывается из совокупности двух значения разом, по идее я ищу строку где param1=1, param2 = 2, что-то типо того, такое точно уникально

Дело в том, что при отсутствии нагрузки скрипт быстро отвечает, разве при плохом селекте у меня бы в принципе скрипт в любой ситуации не грузился бы долго сам по себе?

Ну вот и отгадка

@Ипатьев могу ли я как-то оптимизировать запрос или таблицу? но не могут быть эти поля уникальными никак, что мне делать? планирую почистить таблицу, но это костыль, а не решение. И почему одиночный запрос вне нагрузки тогда прогружается моментально? Если это такая нагруженная операция, она же должна и сама посебе долго отвечать..

Я сейчас действительно проимитировал руками запрос к таблице в этой, он 2 секунды выполняется, когда к остальных маленьких таблиц занимает 0.0008 секунды, осталось понять. как эту проблему решить

Элементарно. Прочитайте свой вопрос. Там написано, что значения в таблице уникальные.

@Ипатьев я очень рад, что Вы знаете лучше меня, поэтому я и пришел сюда за помощью. Значения, по которым я ищу, сами по себе не уникальны, уникальная только пара двух разных полей, по которым я ищу одновременно

Хотя уникальность не принципиальна. Важно, во-первых, наличие индекса, а во вторых - места в памяти для его размещения. А вот места как раз и нет. вшивые 128 метров вместо положенных 10 гигов (если на сервере всего 12)

Ну тем более, сделать надо индекс по двум полям

@Ипатьев поменяю в иннодб на 10 гигов в таком случае, главное, чтобы в других местах с памятью проблем не было. А если вдруг у меня окажется где-то две записи с одинаковыми парами, это может привести к серьезному криту(в случае с индексом)? в принципе, я проверяю перед добавлением, есть ли такая запись, но вдруг так окажется, сервер нагнется там, всякое бывает

@Ипатьев innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size я ещё увидел такой параметр, его тоже нужно поменять?

По итогу я создал общий индекс на два поля, по которым произвожу поиск, а так же выделил 9 гигов оперативы. Пока нет возможности проверить, решило ли это саму проблему, но ручной запрос к таблице теперь вместо 2 секунд занимает 0.003, что похоже на решение проблемы. Спасибо комментатору @Ипатьев за подсказки.
UPDATE 31.07.24
Проблема действительно решилась, убедился на практике, всё отработало, сервак не умер
